# What's the meaning of NSStrokeWidthAttributeName?

Tags: ios, objective-c

> The value of this attribute is an NSNumber object containing a floating-point value. This value represents the amount to change the stroke width and is specified as a percentage of the font point size. Specify 0 (the default) for no additional changes. Specify positive values to change the stroke width alone. Specify negative values to stroke and fill the text. For example, a typical value for outlined text would be 3.0.

I know this value is to modify the stroke width of the paths. And the positive/negative value is to change how to stroke/fill paths.

My question is, what does the value "3.0" mean? If the font point size is 10px, does "3.0" means the stroke width is 30px? I have stroke width px value and font point size px value, what value should I set to NSStrokeWidthAttributeName attribute? Very confusing.